# The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors.?

Tags: android, developer-console

I am trying to update an application in my developer Console , but this is the error I am getting when trying to publish it after uploading the apk.

> The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors.

Comment: If it makes you any better, I'm having the same issue now and nothing helps. Can't publish my APK no matter what I do.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and figured out what I should do. If you click Save as Draft it will take you back and show you the error. In my case it was the target SDK version being lower than what was in the previous version of the app.

Comment: Had the same issue, saved to draft, saw the same error you did although I had not changed the target SDK that I was aware of. I am using Xamarin and had to go into the Xamarin Android Project settings and change `Compile using Android version` from `Use Latest Platform` to a specific version (I just chose the latest one).

Answer (score 6):

#### I had to add a Privacy Policy before I could Unpublish my app.

(That is under *Store presence > Store listing*, at the bottom)

I found that in the first instance because in the menu it highlighted everything it wanted me to look at *(however that was only for the first app, I needed to update 6 but after I followed those menu indicators for the first one they disappeared, even though all my apps needed a privacy policy)*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with one outdated app and that helped me was to fill all new required field for the app, e.g. featured graphics, ratings. After that, it was possible to update the app

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, then I found the solution to this problem. Save your application to draft. Then you will see this error. Move your new version to alpha testing. Now deactivate the current version and move the version in alpha testing to production.

Comment: If you find it useful Please rate the answer up so that more people can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. To solve this issue one must try some of the points below.

1. Check if all the mandatory fields are filled up
2. Check if app's terms and condition has a link
3. Check the distribution page

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. I had an existing app. The issue was that **I was using a hyphen** in the name of the experiment. Apparently, we are not allowed to use it. Hope this helps someone.