# Error while trying to unpublish app from Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to unpublish an app from Google play. When I click unpublish app and confirm it, it gives error like:

> The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors

But the form doesn't show any error. How can I unpbublish app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208117/the-application-could-not-be-saved-please-check-the-form-for-errors

Comment: you should ask google play support. it's their problem.